# Reading Data from web using python

Tags: python, pandas

```
response_object = requests.get("https://testnet.binance.vision/api/v3/exchangeInfo")


response = response_object.json()


response
```

can we read this file in pandas dataframe,its shows wired data when i convert this in pandas data frame or any other way to read this data in python?

Comment: what part of the data do you want to see in a dataframe ? there is very various thing is that

Comment: People often parse html with beautiful soup. I'm assuming you only want the contents of the pre.

Comment: @kpie the full link points to JSON data, not html

Answer (score 0):

You can tabularize the data and place it into a dataframe using json_normalize:

```
df = json_normalize(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Developers using BeatifulSoup For Parsing HTML elements you should use that ! It is easy

For Example  :

and if you want i can send you a video link for watch

```
import time
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from time import sleep
from googletrans import Translator

Translator = Translator()


appOpen = True

while appOpen == True:
    time.sleep(2.5)

    url = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/bulgaria/" #Site Url 
    R = requests.get(url) # For Enter Website

    

    Soup = BeautifulSoup(R.text) # For Parsing

    


    casesDiv = Soup.find("div", {"class" : "news_post"}) # To Fınd a Element from HTML

    casesDiv.findChildren("li", {"class" : "news_li"})

    TransSentences = casesDiv.text

    translation = Translator.translate(TransSentences, dest="tr", src="en")

    

    print(f"{translation.text}".upper())
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, read the request response as json:

`response_data = response_object.json()`

This would create a Python dict with the response data. Then parse the dict in order to get the structure to create Pandas dataframe from.

Then use any of the following methods to convert the structure into DataFrame:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html
- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html
- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html

Comment: I did convert in json,but when i try to normalize this data it given error in data frame.can you please share method to convert into proper data frame.I will be thankfull

Comment: Have you tried to parse the dict in order to get some iterable with every element having the same data type?
Also, which kind of error were you given?